# Translation of a Stata loop into SPSS

Tags: loops, stata, spss

Could anyone help with the translation of the following Stata code? I need this code for further analysis in SPSS.

```
  gen quintile=.
  forvalues i=1/2 {
  xtile quintile`i'= income if income_num==`i', nq(5)
  replace quintile=quintile`i' if income_num==`i'
  drop quintile`i'
    }
```

I tried to solve the problem with the following SPSS code:

```
COMPUTE quintile=($sysmis).

LOOP if #i = 1 to 2.
DO IF (income_num= #i).
FREQUENCIES income 
/ntiles (5) into quintile#i.
DROP = quintile #i.
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
```

But this code appears to be wrong. There are errors in the whole SPSS syntax. First, I would like to know the logical structure of the SPSS Loop in this special case. Second, I ask how to combine this special code with the "Frequencies" command and the "Drop" command.

Do you have any idea how to resolve the problem?

---

The following is a list of the occurring errors.

FREQUENCIES: LOOP has no effect on this command.

FREQUENCIES: The transformations program contains an unclosed LOOP, DO IF, or complex file structure.  Use the level-of-control shown to the left of the SPSS Statistics commands to determine the range of LOOPs and DO IFs.

DROP: LOOP has no effect on this command. 
DROP: The first word in the line is not recognized as an SPSS Statistics command.

END LOOP: The END LOOP command does not follow an unclosed LOOP command.  Maybe the LOOP command was not recognized because of an error.  Use the level-of-control shown to the left of the SPSS Statistics commands to determine the range of LOOPs and DO IFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to take a bit of time to familiarize yourself with SPSS code. (You can't just make things up and expect them to work!) There is no option `into` on the `NTILES` subcommand of frequencies. `FREQUENCIES` simply outputs tables, it does not transform the data in any way.

See the command `RANK` for what you want, something like:

```
RANK VARIABLES = income BY income_num /NTILES(5) INTO quantile.
```

No looping necessary.